# Google maps marker is not showing up with the error chart.apis.google.com/chart 502

Tags: google-maps, google-api, chart.js

I am facing an issue in Google API regarding charts.apis.google.com
and

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()
>
> GET https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=15|acb7bf|FFFFFF 502

Due to this, my location markers are not showing up on the map.
On my live site clients are facing this issue.

I do not know what is the exact issue. Payments are clear, everything is ok.

Please suggest a quick solution for this.

I read 1 post on the google forum.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/1xT15iybzQ4

Please help me out with this issue. 
Much appreciated.

Or any alternative solution.

Thanks

Comment: I am having same issue, did you resolve it

Comment: @MikeFlynn. I just removed this and used the google maps default marker.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I was using something like this below to set an different colored image for the Marker.

var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/•/" + "d3d3d3" + "/");

This was reliant on googlemapsmarkers.com and is no longer working. As soon as I do not use this site to help with the MarkerImage then all is fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been deprecated

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this issue has been recognized in the Issue Tracker via [Issue #128905669](https://issuetracker.google.com/128905669), there is also an alternative solution offered by one of the support from Google which is to use https://www.image-charts.com/